# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Flashlight or headlamp for night hiking?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/flashlight-or-headlamp-for-night-hiking)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What exercises can you do before Scuba Diving to improve your air consumption?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4997/what-exercises-can-you-do-before-scuba-diving-to-improve-your-air-consumption)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [First crampon grade to buy](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/first-crampon-grade-to-buy)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- ["Must Have" in a starter Trad Rack](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4970/must-have-in-a-starter-trad-rack)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to store a backpack while sleeping?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5087/how-to-store-a-backpack-while-sleeping)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Warmth of two sleeping bags](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/warmth-of-two-sleeping-bags)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [When describing my PADI qualifications with a CMAS diver, is there a well know equivalence table?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5077/when-describing-my-padi-qualifications-with-a-cmas-diver-is-there-a-well-know-e)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Freezing fingers and toes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/freezing-fingers-and-toes)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What should I do with possible frostbite: Swollen feet after putting them in warm water](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5055/what-should-i-do-with-possible-frostbite-swollen-feet-after-putting-them-in-war)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What does it need to maintain clothes including membranes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4987/what-does-it-need-to-maintain-clothes-including-membranes)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a very broad range of scores. I'm not sure what that implies. Overall, the total seems positive, but the fact that we have 4 out of 10 that need improvement is a concern to me.

Does this mean we aren't closing off off-topic or rubbish questions where we should be? Or that we are attracting poor quality questions? Or just that this sample of 10 is not really representative?

Comment: Hi rory, bit late I'm afraid. I do feel there is an issue with people unwilling to downote and close bad questions. I've seen quite a few bad question with lots of positive votes. Up voting questions is to be encouraged but only **good** questions.

Comment: I agree - I sometimes feel I am a bit harsh when I vote to close on questions, as I seem to want to do it more than most :-)

Comment: We need to be wary to not turn into another wiki answers. The whole point of SE sites is to weed out the good from the bad. Downvoting and closing is a very important part of this process.

Comment: Oh, I agree 100% - what I meant is that on most sites I am on, I have to consciously not close as many as I sometimes think I should. I am mod on a few sites, so I need to take special care.